# What is the prefered way to deep copy a generic field in java

Tags: java, generics, deep-copy

So I have a generic class which I want to have the method `copy()`:

```java
public class MyGenericClass<T> {

    public MyGenericClass( T value ) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T value;

    public MyGenericClass<T> copy() {
        /* Some way to deep copy 'this' */
    }

}
```

One way I know to do this uses lambda expressions:

```java
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class MyGenericClass<T> {

    public MyGenericClass( T value, UnaryOperator<T> copyLambda ) {
        this.value = value;
        this.copyLambda = copyLambda;
    }

    public T value;

    private final UnaryOperator<T> copyLambda;

    public MyGenericClass<T> copy() {
        return new MyGenericClass<>( copyLambda.apply( value ), copyLambda )
    }

}
```

However this can quickly end up with a huge amount of constructor arguments which would be hard for an individual to manage.

Another way is to require the generic type to implement an interface:

```java
public interface Copyable<T implements Copyable<T>> {
    T copy();
}

public class MyGenericClass<T implements Copyable<T>> implements Copyable<MyGenericClass<T>> {

    public MyGenericClass( T value ) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T value;

    @Override
    public MyGenericClass<T> copy() {
        return new MyGenericClass<>( value.copy )
    }

}
```

(java.util.function.Supplier can be used in exactly the same way only the method would be called `get()` not `copy()`)
But this is also annoying for the end user as all generics they wish to use have to implement this unnecessary interface.

And apparently there is some way to deep copy using serialize and deserialize which sounds rather hacky.

**Which one of these approaches should I use?**

Do I use lambda expressions for copying things and create a factory class to deal with the long constructors?

Or do I require all generics that end up as field types to implement an interface?

Comment: "However this can quickly end up with a huge amount of constructor arguments which would be hard for an individual to manage." Why? You've only shown one extra constructor argument, so you haven't really got your point across...

Comment: @Sweeper, what I showed was an extra argument for every generic type that would be used in a copy. In the example that only adds another parameter but if a class has for example 4 fields with unique generic types that would add a requirement for an extra 4 parameters which can make for long constructors. (Perhaps huge was an overstatement)

Comment: Well, how else is the caller going to tell `MyGenericClass` how to copy the generic types? If you don't like like long constructors, how about using a builder-like pattern? e.g. `new MyGenericClass(someT, someU, someV).withTCopier(...).withUCopier(...).withVCopier(...)`